# Arduino due + mcp2551

Tags: arduino-due, can-bus

I am currently using an atmega328 along with the mcp 2515 and the 2551 for CAN communication in my systems.

However, I've now decided to upgrade to the arduino due for my operations. Can anybody tell me if the arduino due along with it's inbuilt CAN controller be used with the mcp2551 transciever to operate CAN successfully.

If not, can somebody also tell me if there are other alternatives I should look into. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest trouble you are going to find is the voltage levels. The MCP2551 works at 5V and your MCU is 3.3V. I personally don't have experience with this MCUs, but some STM32 MCUs are 5V tolerant on some pins, including the CAN_TX and Can_RX and it's fine to use a 5V Transceiver like the MCP2551.

Anyway, you still can replace the CAN Transceiver with one that has a built in level shifter,  like one of the following:

- MCP2562
- ATA6561
- SN65HVD256
- NCV7351D13

I've used all the above, except the TI one, and they all talk nicely between each other. Some have different features, like silence or advanced sleeping modes.

Cheers

Comment: The Arduino Due is definitely not 5V tolerant. From https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDue: "The maximum voltage that the I/O pins can tolerate is 3.3V. Applying voltages higher than 3.3V to any I/O pin could damage the board."